# Starting multiple sddm sessions automatically

Tags: linux, tty, kodi, kde-plasma-5, sddm

I'm trying to achieve a relatively simple thing in theory, but having a lot of problems with it. I'm trying to have my Arch Linux (though this issue is somewhat general and not specific to distro I think) PC start multiple SDDM sessions, one with KDE Plasma and one with Kodi, each with different user on different tty. I can do that "manually" simply by using the "Switch user" option in plasma menu, which creates new sddm "instance" on tty2 (when my Plasma desktop is still running on tty1), I'm able to login to the Kodi session with kodi dedicated user and switch back and forth via the Ctrl+Fx combination. That works great and is what I need.

The problem is, I haven't found a solution to automate this with a script. My ideal setup would be to have both of those sessions configured to autologin, therefore not having to input credentials when the PC starts and both of those sessions to start after startup, without need of any input. But having at least the login screen for both sessions started automatically would be at least a step in the right direction.

I'm using X11 and would like to make this work on that, since Wayland still has some usability issues for me (mainly not having mouse gestures). I'm also trying to avoid not using SDDM and starting the X server manually via startx, I think of that as a last resort - I've already tried that, but Kodi kept popping up in tty1 regardless of where it was started from and overall it felt very "hacky".

My thinking is that if this can be achieved by clicking a button in plasma, the function is there somewhere and it should be possible to automate it, but I haven't been able to find any solution, either by googling or by tinkering myself.

Thanks very much in advance for any ideas!